# Does Redux affect preformance in React-js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to figure out if it's better to use redux or not, my main concern is the vertical scalability i.e. the performance.

I actually prefer to not use redux, but it seems so popular in a lot of back-end stacks, I was wondering if anyone has ever made a comparison by building a larger application to compare the speed.

The performance page on redux's site was not very helpful, as it basically only talks about performance within redux.
https://redux.js.org/docs/faq/Performance.html#performance-all-reducers

I did find a lot about how it's better in practice to use Redux, like in this article below, but I don't think It quite answers my concerns
https://css-tricks.com/learning-react-redux/

Please let me know what you think.

Comment: what kind of performance issues are you concerned with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I actually prefer to not use redux

Then you don't need redux. There is a post by the creator of Redux - "You Might Not Need Redux" that talks about your problem - https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367

There are many factors that decide whether to use Redux or not. Personally, I like Redux because it is so much easier to manage the state of your React application. It offers great separation of concerns, keeps your code clean and minimal and on top of all, as your application grows larger and complicated, Redux makes it easier to scale and maintain.

I haven't faced any performance issues with Redux so far. It is actually the opposite. Since my code tends to be cleaner with the use of Redux, there are fewer bugs.

That said, if you do not set up things properly, you might face the consequences.

Redux isn't slow, you're just doing it wrong - An optimization guide - https://reactrocket.com/post/react-redux-optimization/

Comment: Thank you, the first article actually cleared up a lot of questions and concerns I had about Redux, and doing a little more research I have seen how people tend to love the fact that everything is conveniently placed in one store making it easier to manipulate the app especially if they want to affect multiple components in the same window when one particular state is affected. I would say Redux is worth using in certain situations, I'll definitely have to play around with it more.

Comment: Thanks for the optimization guide as well.